# Could this lindworm survive as a predator?

Tags: mythical-creatures, anatomy, food, dragons, snake

My lindworm is a dragon with a rather classical form.

They have a long body like a snake, and move by slithering. At their chest they have a pair of arms with raptorial claws. Their necks are long and flexible. They are around the same size as an anaconda

They hunt like snakes, with their claws being used to catch and kill their prey. They also have a venom, which is injected by a bite. Their native environment is quite close to that of Europe

However, I'd like to give it a head like a rhinoceros. This seems like it could cause problems: Specifically, rhinoceroses are rather specialized herbivores, and so have very few adaptations for eating meat like these lindworms. However, it seems plausible at least that the dentition and other superficial features could be reworked for carnivory while retaining the desired shape

**Could a predator with a rhinoceros' head survive as a carnivore?**

Comment: In what way is the answer not "of course it can! -- all you've done is change the external appearance of the lindworm's head! Obviously, a carnivorous  lindwocerous would have a horn on its snout and some good strong canines and carnassials for munching and crunching their prey.

Comment: Maybe handy to put a link to get an idea, "lindworm" is about a creature found in German and Nordic heraldry.. examples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindworm

Comment: "They hunt like snakes, with their claws being used to catch and kill their prey." I believe that's not how snakes hunt, so can you explain how they hunt exactly? How do they slither, if they have claws on their chest? In what way are their heads like rhinoceroses?

Answer (score 2):

[Sexual selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_selection) can cause all sorts of otherwise useless features to become very important for allowing their bearer to reproduce.  While horns may be useful for self-defence for a herbivore, they may also be useful for attracting female - or male - lindworms.  If having a big, sexy horn on your snout is what it takes a lindworm to get laid, by evolution, that's what's going to evolve!  Weight and inconvenience be damned!  I'm strong enough to carry this big, useless, sexy thing around and still be healthy, so I must be good breeding material!

Any time you see a large, decorative, useless something on an animal, the reason is probably sexual selection.

I'd say that if these horns are sexual signals, but both males and females have them, their appearance would differ between males and females.  There's no point attracting members of the same sex, after all (sorry, evolution doesn't care about homosexuality, since it doesn't lead to offspring).

As a case in point: [The Horned Viper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerastes_cerastes)

Answer (score 0):

**Precedent: Ceratosaurus!**

[image: ceratosaurus]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceratosaurus

So you can be a predator and have a horn on your nose.  Maybe two.  Big ones got three.

I propose your lindworm needs these horns to protect its head - evolutionarily it is less evolved than other snakes (to wit: it's got legs!) and must chew its venom in rather than inject it.  This takes a while and the large prey animals vigorously try to dislodge the lindworm.  The horns serve the shield the head from kicks and scratches during that needed chewing.

Comment: *"to protect its head"* Q: why would a predator need to defend its head ? It should have an accurate bite, it will use its teeth.. The predator's head is the most dangerous part, because of the teeth. Why would it need a spike on top ? Extra weight would not be handy. It would make the head less agile and it would slow down the killing bite.  I also found the reconstruction of Ceratosaurus varies.. Brittanica shows this "horn" far less prominent https://www.britannica.com/animal/Ceratosaurus

Comment: @Goodies - it is more awesome with the big horn.  They were not afraid to make their dinosaurs awesome back then.    Maybe the lindworm uses them to duel other lindworms.  And probably the lady lindworms like a male who has the core strength to sport serious horns and still go hunting.

Comment: Ah for the *lady* lindworm the horn only needs a fancy color, that would do.. I think the Ceratosaurus horn is shown much too spike-like and heavy in the picture in Wiki. I don't believe a predator has any use for this horn, it is only slowing movement, because of the mass. Maybe if it was developed for mating rituals and fights among eachother, the animal was strong enough, could afford it ? Keep in mind Ceratosaurus lived only 10 million years in the late jurassic. Failed experiment wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: This question was about a rhinoceros-type head, not the horn

Comment: @IchthysKing - then you will need to unpack what you mean by that.  Rhinos have an elongated head, a horn or 2, little but protuberant ears, mobile lips, grinding teeth, small eyes.  All that?

Comment: @IchthysKing your question was "can it survive ?". My comment just mentions some evolutionary disadvantages of having an heavy horn on the nose, for a *predator*. Of course you may insist on a rhino head, Willk's answer will do fine. Awesome picture indeed.. and the Ceratosaurus species lived ten million years.